# Checkboxes are running macro on selected cell row; Need them to run on linked cell row

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a workbook in which specific line items are to be completed by a staff member and, once completed, they are to be checked off as complete. This triggers the row/range to the left of the checkbox to be selected, copied and pasted into the next worksheet on the first available row. The current row is then cleared from the first worksheet. Each worksheet has the checkboxes pre-filled in and pre-linked to cells. The issue I'm having is that when the checkbox is selected, the runall macro activates on the row that is currently selected instead of the row that the checkbox resides in and is linked to the cell in. So, for example, if the checkbox is in row M2 but the currently selected cell is B8, the macro will try to copy and paste row 8 instead of the intended row 2. As there is no undo with macros this results in a major headache. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub RUNALLOPEN()
Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to clear this row and send to the Lab?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirm Error Resolution")
If response = vbNo Then
    Dim cbx As CheckBox
    Set cbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    With cbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1)
    cbx.Value = xlOff
    End With
    Exit Sub
End If
If response = vbYes Then
'rest of code
    Call movedataOPEN2LAB
    Call clearcellsOPEN
     End If
End Sub


    Sub movedataOPEN2LAB()
 Dim cbx As CheckBox

        'Application.Caller returns the name of the CheckBox that called this macro
        Set cbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

        '.TopLeftCell returns the cell address located at the top left corner of the cbx checkbox
        With cbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1)

            'Check the checkbox status (checked or unchecked)
            If cbx.Value = xlOn Then
            ' Checkbox is Checked
     Range(Cells(cbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Row, 1), Cells(cbx.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Row, 11)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Sheets("Lab").Select
     Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Selection.Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(""G"" & ROW()),'Source Data'!$D$1:$J$36,6,FALSE)"
     ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Selection.Row).Value = "Lab"
     Range("A2").Select
  End If
        End With
End Sub


Sub clearcellsOPEN()
 On Error Resume Next
 Worksheets("Open").Activate
 Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 15)).Select
 Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
 Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 1)).Select
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help! Here's what I came up with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 13 Then
'If UCase(Target.Value) <> "X" Then
'   Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
'    response = MsgBox("You must input 'x' in order to move this row.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "ERROR")
'    Exit Sub
'    End If
If UCase(Target.Value) = "X" Then
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to clear this row and send to the Lab?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirm Error Resolution")
If response = vbNo Then
    Target.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
If response = vbYes Then
'rest of code
Target.Cells.Offset(0, -12).Select
     Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     With Sheets("Lab")
     .Select
     .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
     End With
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Selection.Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(""G"" & ROW()),'Source Data'!$D$1:$J$36,6,FALSE)"
     ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Selection.Row).Value = "Lab"
     With Sheets("Open")
     .Select
     On Error Resume Next
     Target.Cells.Offset(0, -12).Select
     Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14)).Select
     Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
     End With
     End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've often tried to plan ahead on using insert-objects/buttons because they are not directly tied to locations on the sheet (Though they can be positioned based on the sheet).  Depending on number of checkboxes, as this could take some time, you can rename your checkboxes to have the associated row as the first so many characters in the name, then you can use Left(checkbox name, #) to fill in the appropriate row.

Comment: Another option is to get rid of checkboxes, use data-validation lists to toggle true/false, then do a change event based on the target cell (e.g. dim r as long, r = target.row; the column is known).

Comment: A checkbox-based solution like this is very fallure-prone. As @Cyril suggests, use data validation instead and a Worksheet_Change event instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other ways to accomplish that than checkboxes... A "cleaner" one that comes to my mind is to use the Change event of the worksheet.

1. get rid of the checkboxes
2. Set the title of Column M to "Completed = X"
3. Use this code in the Table Object:

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Target.Column = 13 Then
           If uCase(Target.Value) = "X" Then
               '--Write your copy-code here maybe ignore/delete the x first
               MsgBox "CopyThat!"
           End If
       End If
   End Sub

just a suggestion...

Comment: I posted an updated code above using your suggestions. I would ideally like a msgbx to appear if any character that <> "x" is entered into the cell and then for the cell contents to be cleared, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this without throwing the sheet into a msgbox loop. For now I have left as far as I've gotten with that part of the code greyed out (or greened out) at the beginning. Any suggestions?

Thanks again for the assistance!